# How to insert date time in Indian Standard time and upon retrieval format datetime to date only in php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am developing a website in which on particular event on the website $query is executed and entry is made in the db in user_id and store used and order_date Field .Order_date is of type datetime in which current timestamp value gets automatically inserted upon entry.But to the dismay the server is hosted in US so the time getting inserted is of US,so i wanted it to be in the ist format and also when i am retrieving the values i want to format it such that only time appears.Have googled a lot but none of them worked.Please Help

```
<!--Insertion Query -->

$querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
                        "VALUES ('$coola', 'Airtel')";


<!--Retrieval Query -->


'<td align="center">'.$row['order_no'].'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$row['order_date'].'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$row['store_used'].'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$row['cashback'].'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$row['est_cashback_date'].'</td>'.
```

Comment: did you google how to save time such as GMT+10 or 11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i wanted `order_date` to be in the IST format

You can set `time_zone` per connection basis to a specific timezone like `IST` as [Documented Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html). probably you can also do the same using `PHP` but not sure about that.

```
SET time_zone = 'IST';
```

> upon retrieval format datetime to date only in php?

You can use [`DATE(expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to get only the date part like

```
select date(order_date) as order_date
from orderdata;
```

Per your commented SQL, you can do it like

```
SELECT i.order_no,
date(i.order_date) as order_date,
i.store_used,
i.status,
i.cashback,
i.est_cashback_date 
FROM orderdata as i 
WHERE i.user_id =$a 
ORDER BY i.order_date DESC 
$limit
```

Comment: This is my select query can u please elaborate what are you trying to say by updating same in this piece of code                                   $sql="SELECT i.order_no,i.order_date,i.store_used,i.status,i.cashback,i.est_cashback_date FROM orderdata as i WHERE user_id =$a ORDER BY order_date DESC $limit";
    $query=mysqli_query($dbc2,$sql);

Comment: Yup thanks mate it helped but what about the Gmt thing have you got any idea about that too?

Comment: @Abhishek, didn't get you. What GMT thing you are talking about?

Comment: i have field name order_date of type time with value current_timestamp .When any insertion takes place the times also gets inserted but it is in Us gmt how can i convert it so that it is saved in ist?Got my point?

Comment: @Abhishek, yes can be done. Post a separate question for that and consider providing the link here as comment.